# Get around grid in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, grid, responsive

I'm trying to create 2 grid the first one have two buttons and the other one have a title I want to make the second grid get around the first one ...
here's my code>>

```
                            <Grid x:Name="pgtitle" >
                            <StackPanel x:Name="btn" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <AppBarButton Icon="More" Tapped="more_Tapped"/>
                                    <AppBarButton Icon="List" Click="view_Click"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <RelativePanel x:Name="title">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="titletxt" Text="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedItem.Title}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </RelativePanel>
                        </Grid>
```

here's a picture for what am I trying to do>>

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "get around" as in flow around, similarly to news articles and texts, that is not possible. All layout elements in XAML are rectangular and they don't take other sibling elements into account.

You can display the inner `Grid` in one column and other elements in second column, but the contents of such columns must be known beforehand.

Comment: Yes i've meant get around the first grid ... I'll try this but i hope to find a better one :/

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `RelativePanel` element in UWP where you can place elements right or left of other elements. I think this can be achieved with that control.

For example, the RelativePanel will contain the smaller grid you have in your picture and will be the anchor to all other elements. You will have to set the other elements (children of the larger grid) to go on the right or bottom of the smaller grid.